# Find the Subfield diagram of splitting field of $x^{33}-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field, cyclotomic-fields

Find the subfield diagram of splitting field of $x^{33}-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

This problem seems hard. I cannot find the fields using the automorphisms, because the basis is too large and so it would be too many computation. I know the galaois group is $Z_{10} \times Z_2$ thus we have $4$ non trivial subfields. I think I found $3$ $\mathbb{Q}(z_{11})$,$\mathbb{Q}(z_{3})$,$\mathbb{Q}(z_{33}+z_{33}^{-1})$  However, i am not sure how to find the inclusions, and what is the last subfield i ma missing. This is a problem on an algebra qual so should be doable using standard Galois theory.

Comment: What about $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{11}+\zeta_{11}^{-1})$?

Comment: Cyclic subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}_{10}\times\Bbb{Z}_2$ generated by one of $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(2,1)$ (order ten), $(2,0)$ (order five), $(5,0),(0,1),(5,1)$ (order two) all seem distinct to me. Then there is also a non-cyclic order four subgroup $\langle(5,0),(0,1)\rangle$.

Comment: Anyway, the identification of the Galois group as $\Bbb{Z}_{10}\times\Bbb{Z}_2$ plays very well together with the generating set $\zeta_{11}$, $\zeta_3$ so I would use that.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen They are the generating set because their multiple is the 33-rd root of unity correct? It still seems computationally heavy as the basis has $12$ elements.

Comment: You can also use the fact that when $q=2p+1$, $p,q$ both odd primes, the non-trivial subfields of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_q)$ are the quadratic $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-q})$ and the real subfield $\Bbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/q)$ that's a degree $p$ extension. That result appears often together with Gauss sums (and Gauss sign problem). May depend on who was teaching Algebra whether it  was covered?

Comment: And any basis has 20 elements, not twelve. Don't make that kind of mistakes in quals :-)